# Using getLoginStatus to fire a Js redirect

Tags: javascript, authorization, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use Fb.getLoginStatus to implement a Js redirect to another page IF the user is logged in to Facebook upon coming to my website AND connected to my Fb app. It's not working and I don't know why! Is this possible? Any advice would be gratefully received.

Here's my code - I'm using a PHP include to insert it into my page, and it appears the Fb Javascript SDK init function is working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'my-app-id',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
      channelUrl  : 'http://www.jamesherlihy.com/sandbox/fb-channel.html', // Custom Channel URL
      oauth : true //enables OAuth 2.0
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    /* if user is logged in to Fb and connected to Soulmap, redirect them to logged-in homepage */

    if (response.authResponse){
    window.location = "http://www.jamesherlihy.com/fb-03-logged-in.php";
    }

    /* if user is NOT logged in to Fb and/or connected to Soulmap, do not execute any script */

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a `<div id="fb-root"></div>` somewhere in your page because the script references it.

Comment: Hi OffBySome, thanks for the response! It's a good idea, as I have left that out before, but in this case I do have the '<div id="fb-root"></div>' on the page directly before this script. So it's not that in this case.

Comment: I'm testing with other more simple Js commands and it appears that the getLoginStatus function just isn't working for me.